# Can I control the current in a Cat5/6 cable?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, hardware, signal-processing

We have a motorized table at work. The motor is controlled by a small control panel which is connected through a regular cat5/6 cable. I dissected the cable and found that by connecting certain wires together, I send the correct signals to the table and the motor starts.

My laptop has two network cable slots. Would it be possible to do what I'm currently doing physically, in software? I.e., by connecting the wires in physical position 3 and 5 in the cable, the table moves up. Thus the question is, can I target my free cat5 slot and simulate that two pins are shorted, enabling the signal to go through and hence move the table?

Comment: Control the currents in a cable? Yes. Control the currents and pin-assignments of an ethernet connector in a computer? No. Using something like an Arduino you should be able to build an USB-to-table control though.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking of Arduino too. But the table-interface uses a cat5 cable, so unfortunately I'm bound to that. Anyway, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1):

That might be possible, but just because it uses the same connector doesn't mean that the pins have to be used the same way.

**Before you even plug it in your computer**, you should check what those pins do in the network interface, and also what the state is of other pins in the connector of the table and what those do in the network interface.

Unless the table interface is carefully constructed to actually be compatible with a regular network socket, it's quite likely that you will fry the I/O chip in the computer, and possibly also something in the table.

Comment: Yes, of course. It's highly likely that the cable interface was chosen for convenience. As far as I know, only three of the pins are used. That said, cat5 is approved for up to over 40V, so intuitively the I/O chip should sustain the same voltage.

Comment: @Pedery: That's the specification for the cable, not the network interface. That current is used for Power over Ethernet, singal current is a lot lower, typically less than 3 volt.